# Import AJAX data into an array. [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a simple AJAX script to load a file into an array.

```
var loadGame = function() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      game = this.responseText
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('GET', 'games/' + $('.meta').html() + '.game', true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

However, `game` is treated as a string, not an array, even if `this.responseText` is a valid array. How can I get JS to treat `this.responseText` as an array when I store it to `game`?

Comment: perhaps JSON.parse will help

Comment: Can you elaborate? I've seen something like this, but I'm really looking for a built in command to convert between types.

Comment: can I elaborate? Better than that, I can link to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) ... `built in command to convert between types` - what does the received data look like ... **exactly**

Comment: The file contents: `['a','b']`, and how AJAX import it: `"['a','b']"`.

Comment: you should send `{arr: ['a', 'b']}` from the server

Comment: yeah, unfortunately that wont parse using JSON.parse - it likes " instead of ' ...

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij - that wont parse either - and there's no need to add complexity to the data returned, no reason it should be an object with an array property

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `{arr: ['a', 'b']}`. Am I modifying the file directly on the server?

Comment: @JaromandaX oh yeah, well but `{"arr": ["a", "b"]}` would work.

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij - so would `["a", "b"]` - which is why I asked why you'd need to add extra complexity

Comment: But it _doesn't_ work at all. The file I am reading is a plain text file. Trying any of these things produces the same result - The entire thing is imported as a string.

Comment: @JulianLachniet - which JSON.parse will handle, as long as the string is in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

because the file uses `'` to delimit strings, JSON.parse wont work

the following may help depending on the data

```
game = JSON.parse(this.responseText.split("'").map(function(x) { return x.replace(/"/gm, "'"); }).join('"'));
```

If any values have ' or " in then, this wont work very well though

Another far simpler solution is using eval ...

```
eval("game=" + this.responseText);
```

Just be careful using eval

Answer (score 0):

xhttp.responseText is always a string. however, you can get it as an array using `JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)`. Before you can use `JSON.parse`, you should encode it in json in the server. in php, you can do it is json_encode function. like the following

```
    //php
  $response = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
  echo json_encode($response);
```

using `JSON.parse` in the client will return ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I am importing from a file already in array format.

Comment: so, simply use JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText) to get it in array format.